# Failures: Angular js testing tool protractor error for testing a application

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

while compiling cfg file we getting this error.

```
 Failures:
    1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
      Message:
        Failed: element not visible
          (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb0
    42aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provid
    e any stacktrace information)
        Command duration or timeout: 120 milliseconds
        Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:
    03'
        System info: host: 'Guest684', ip: '172.17.13.252', os.name: 'Windows 8.1',
    os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
        Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulati
    onEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.2
    6.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30), userDataDir=C:\Users\miracl
    e\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9992_4680}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrat
    egy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, ver
    sion=55.0.2883.87, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents
    =true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
     browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssS`enter code here`electorsE
    nabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
        Session ID: 9601e64df3743dbf5dc215bd39d4f528
      Stack:
        ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is getting downvoted because it is poorly formatted and provides too little information. It is not clear what exactly leads to the error (i.e. what is cfg?).

Comment: It appears you are doing the `Protractor App Demo`. Providing the stacktrace is not enough, you'll also need to provide a configuration file and a sample spec file that causes this error. From the error, I can tell you that your element was not visible but that's it.

Answer (score -1):

Please use protractor Configuration and Specification file for your protractor test.

Configuration file should have - Selenium Port address, Browser info and Specification file name

Specification file should have -  Test Steps and Verification Part.

Comment: This should be a comment on the post, not an answer.